# ipython notebook server behind VPN

Tags: webserver, ipython

Hi I am trying to set up a ipython notebook server at a machine at my school and access from outside the network

I can ssh to the machine after connecting to the school VPN.

I set up the ipython notebook to listen to all the ip address. I can open chrome/firefox to connect to it within the network.

```
The IPython Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:9999/
```

But I can't access the notebook from outside the network (even with VPN)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [all ip addresses on your system] to your VPN whitelist, typically is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. If this still does not work, check if you are using global mode of your VPN which might overlook the whitelist config.